# How to decompose this component for better separation of concerns?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, components, single-page-application

[image]

I want to design a component that has this UI. However, what I've come up with seems very bloated and I feel that it could be broken down even further for better separation of concerns.

What I've done is simply made the entire card into a single component where you can pass in the following params

```
<ResourceCard 
imageUrl="https://imageUrl.com"
iconUrl="https://iconimageUrl.com"
type="WEBINAR"
typeDescription="60 min video"
bodyTitle="Holiday Email: What to Know Before You Send"
body="Learn from our team of email..."
ctaText="Watch the webinar"
ctaUrl="https://exampleLink.com"
/>
```

Can this be separated further? Essentially I only have 1 component which handles rendering AND implementation of every section of this card. But I'm unsure what the best practice is when breaking something like this card down into further components.

Comment: I don' think further separation will required in this design as most of the elements are just a text and images. So I did not find any specific section in this card which can be reuse.

Comment: Depends on your case. Some parts, especially the ones that may contain markup or comps like router-link instead of plain text (e.g body) can be slots instead of props